# Present perfect for lasting action up to now

Tags: present-perfect

> I **have been getting** / **have gotten** everything they have released so far

I think both can fit  but may be continuous is a bit better as it goes  up to now and the action of getting is a continuous thing

Comment: I think the first way of saying it puts emphasis on the action of buying or acquiring everything they have released so far and the second way of saying it puts emphasis on your current state of actually having (possessing) everything they have released so far through buying it. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: @Michael Rybkin Is it possible to "have been getting everything?" Do you mean in the sense of acquiering their releases bit by bit over a period of time?

Comment: @anouk I think it has more to do with context and how exactly it is phrased. I don't think that semantics is directly governed by grammar.

Comment: @ Michael Rybkin I still don't understand "have been getting everything".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about having gotten all that has been released up to the present, then 'have gotten' is better. If you are saying that up until now you have been getting everything they've released, then the continuous is better, but for that meaning, it would be much clearer if the qualifier 'so far' were at the head of the sentence:
So far, I have been getting everything they have released.

Comment: i don't see the difference between  u p to the present and until now for me it is the same what is the difference ?

Comment: There is no difference. They are equivalent. What I was referring to is the difference between 'released until now' and 'gotten until now'. If you have gotten all that they have released until now, that getting is all in the past, so 'have gotten' applies. If you are talking about the process of your receiving, that extends up until the present moment, so the progressive fits.

Comment: So both can fits it depends on what the speaker or writer wants to emphasize

Comment: the result present perfect, or the act of getting progressive that extends to until now